# "Sorry but miktex makemf did not succeed" and udpmap not solving problem

Tags: miktex

thank you for reading this question.

I installed miktex as user(not as admin) (since company has strict cyber security standards, I have no other choice like using texlive or install new fonts) and try to run this example

```latex
\documentclass{ctexart}

\setCJKmainfont[
AutoFakeBold,AutoFakeSlant
]{SimSun}

\begin{document}

hello world, \textbf{你好}

\end{document}
```

I ran it by TeXworks, then
the console output complains

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "SimHei" cannot be found.
```

It should be able to bypass the error by `AutoFakeBold` and `AutoFakeSlant`, since it works in my personal computer.

I look into the console output of TeXworks and the differences are there are lots of

```
Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed.
```

and

```
Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed.
```

in the unsuccessful compilation, so I tried the solution of this question
but they don't work. When I type `updmap.exe` alone, the problem remains
, and when I use option `force` or `admin` the cmd returns

```
C:\Users\Test Virtual Machine>updmap.exe --force
Incorrect usage: --force: unknown option

C:\Users\Test Virtual Machine>updmap.exe --admin

Sorry, but: option --admin only makes sense for a shared MiKTeX setup
```

Comment: SimHei is not SimSun, and updmap has nothing to do with using fonts with fontspec. Try `\documentclass[fontset=fandol]{ctexart}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is originally from @Ulrike Fischer's comment. Thanks to you, Ulrike Fischer.

I tried it and it succeeded. The CTeX Package Documentation（2022/07/14 v2.5.10） wrote that(I translated it into English, and may not very accurate)

> If you want to set font at preamble by `\ctexset`, it's required that set `fontset = none` when declaring document class

Maybe that's why Ulrike Fischer's way works. Besides, I tried to set `fontset = none` when declaring document class and simply use

```
\setCJKmainfont[
AutoFakeBold,AutoFakeSlant
]{SimSun}
```

Then the console output do not complain

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "SimHei" cannot be found.
```

There are still lots of `Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed.`, I don't know why but these don't hinder the compilation, you can still get the desired output